# Sending a form via PHPMailer to an EMail adress - not working

Tags: forms, phpmailer

I am trying to implement a form on my website - and make a PHPMailer send the content to my email address. I followed the directions from this website: https://www.codingsnow.com/2021/01/create-php-send-email-contact-form.html

But its not working. I tried different email addresses, I tried tls and other ports and many more - nothing. Its alway the same: When I click the submit button, nothing happens. There's neither a success nor a failed echo.

I could really need some help!

This is the form code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        input, textarea {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center">
                <input id="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
                <input id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                <input id="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="body" placeholder="Email Body"></textarea>
                <input type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Send an Email" class="btn btn-primary"></type>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendEmail() {
        console.log('sending...');
        var name = $("#name");
        var email = $("#email");
        var subject = $("#subject");
        var body = $("#body");

        if (isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(subject)  && isNotEmpty(body)) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sendEmail.php',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    name: name.val(),
                    email: email.val(),
                    body: body.val()
                }, success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function isNotEmpty(caller) {
        if (caller.val() === "") {
            caller.css('border', '1px solid red');
            return false;
        } else {
            caller.css('border', '');
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the sendEmail.php:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
    require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    //smtp settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

    //email settings
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = ("$email ($subject)");
    $mail->Body = $body;

    if($mail->send()){
        $status = "success";
        $response = "Email is sent!";
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "failed";
        $response = "Something is wrong: <br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
}

  if ($mail->send()) {
        $status = "success";
        echo "Email is sent!";
    } else {
        $status = "failed";
     echo   "Something is wrong: <br><br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

?>
```

Thank you for your time and knowledge!
Andre

P.S.: @Merchizm: Thanks, I have changed the code, now it looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

if(isset.... and so on
```

Is this, what you mean?

I also added the jQuery to the head of the html file like this:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery30102019.js"></script>
```

But nevertheless, it is not working. Still the same issue.

Do you have another idea?
Thanks Andre

Answer (score 0):

- The JQuery library is not included in the html file, the request may not be going because of this.
- Require files before using class.

```
require_once __DIR__. "/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
require_once  __DIR__."/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php";
require_once  __DIR__."/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

I think these will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is still there, unfortunately...

Comment: Can you try a different email provider instead of gmail? If you are not having problems with a different email provider, the problem may be due to gmail's security measures. Via [link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)
You can activate the specified setting and try again.

Comment: I already tried that. I disabled the security measures at gmail, I tried different hosts like strato and yahoo.de... but no change. So, you think there is no problem in the codes?

Comment: I just had an idea: if this is indeed a Gmail (or other provider) problem and the code is fine, shouldn't there at least be an echo when I click the submit button? But there is no echo at all... I appreciate your help!

Comment: Okay, its a pity. Can someone at least recommend another code, that is working without jQuery? Maybe someone has an existing example on a website? (I already tried four or five of that examples, but not a single one worked for me.) Thanks! Andre